# 一 (one) kanji onyomi pronunciations

Tags: kanji, readings, multiple-readings

The 一 (one) kanji has two onyomi pronunciations: ICHI and ITSU. When do you use them?

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you some examples.

**ICHI**

> 一月　【いちがつ】

Meaning: January

Example:

彼【かれ】の知事【ちじ】としての任期【にんき】は来年【らいねん】の一月【いちがつ】に切れる【きれる】。

His term of office as governor expires next January.

> 十一　【じゅういち】

Meaning: Eleven

Example:

ジェーンは十一歳【じゅういっさい】の時【とき】からずっと映画【えいが】に出演【しゅつえん】している。(See @psosuna's note on this reading)

Jane has been acting in movies since she was eleven.

> 一億　【いちおく】

Meaning: One hundred million

Example:

おまえはどうして、百匹【ひゃくひき】のねこ、千匹【せんひき】のねこ、百万匹　【ひゃくまんひき】、一億【いちおく】、一兆匹【いっちょうひき】のねこといっしょに、食べられて【たべられて】しまわなかったのだね。

How does it happen that you were not eaten up with all those hundreds and trillions of cats?

> 一連　【いちれん】

Meaning: series;  chain;  sequence

Example:

彼ら【かれら】は一連【いちれん】の音楽会【おんがくかい】を開催【かいさい】した。

They gave a series of concerts.

> 一位　【いちい】

Meaning: first place;  first rank;  unit's position

Example:

みんなが驚いた【おどろいた】ことに、マイクはスピーチコンテストで一位【いちい】を取った【とった】。

To everyone's astonishment, Mike won first prize in the speech contest.

---

**ITSU**

> 統一 【とういつ】

Meaning: unity;  consolidation;  uniformity;  unification;  compatible

Example:

建築【けんちく】のシンメトリーで、エメットは美的【びてき】統一【とういつ】性【せい】をもった幾何【きか】学【がく】的【てき】な対称【たいしょう】性【せい】を意味【いみ】している。

By architectural symmetry, Emmet means geometric symmetry combined with aesthetic uniformity.

> 不統一　【ふとういつ】

Meaning: disunity;  disharmony

Example:

委員会【いいんかい】は意見【いけん】が不統一【ふとういつ】である.

The committee are divided in their opinions.

> 択一　【たくいつ】

Meaning: choosing an alternative

Example:

彼【かれ】は二者択一【にしゃたくいつ】を選ぶ【えらぶ】ことでしょう。武術【ぶじゅつ】か死【し】か。

Which will he choose I wonder? Martial arts, or death?

---

**Conclusion**: 一 (one) can have many readings depending on if using onyomi or kunyomi ([see my opinion here on that](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/52178/do-we-really-need-remember-kunyomi-and-onyomi-reading-of-each-kanji/52179#52179)) Basically you should remember within context instead of trying to memorize readings, but that's my perspective.

Comment: Quick extra note: It is the いつ reading for 一 that leads to compound words such as 一ヶ月(いっかげつ), 一緒(いっしょ), and so on. Basically, all the words that use っ