# Is "made of wood" 木【き】 or 木【もく】 here?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

> 木【き】や紙【かみ】でできたストローが、当【あ】たり前【まえ】の時代【じだい】がすぐそこにやってきている

*The era when straws made of wood or paper will be the norm is just around the corner.*

https://www.fnn.jp/articles/-/340720

I am aware of the words

木造【もくぞう】 wooden

木製【もくせい】 wooden

and of course 木曜日【もくようび】 "wood-day" (Thursday)

but j-talk.com produced the reading 木【き】 for the sentence above. Is it correct?

Comment: Do you understand the different between kun'yomi and on'yomi?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/6200/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52179/9831 See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/52180/9831 `If you see the character on its own, you've likely got a kunyomi. (...) If you see the character with other kanji, it's likely an onyomi.`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the difference between on and kun readings.
There are exceptions to the rule, which is why I posted my question.

水: Kun: みず、 みず- On: スイ

お水【おみず】drinking water
水筒【すいとう】water bottle
水着【みずぎ】swimsuit
水際【みずぎわ】coastline

木 Kun: き、 こ- On: ボク、 モク

木材【もくざい】lumber, timber, wood
木炭【もくたん】charcoal
白木【しらき】plain wood, unfinished woodwork
木箱【きばこ】wooden box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently 木（モク） is a jargon and can be used by architects and other professionals related to the field, presumably to make it less ambiguous.

https://a-a-o.net/20120208/

> 現場は木（モク）の迫力ある光景です。

https://dlisv03.media.osaka-cu.ac.jp/contents/osakacu/kiyo/111H0000010-2-07.pdf

> 木（モク）でも、耐火性能が高い、不燃材扱いのものがありますね。

For the vast majority of cases 木 as a material and as a non-compound word is read き. Stories written by journalists like this one would be among them.

Answer (score 0):

Generally difference in reading does not imply that of meaning. 木 means something related to trees regardless of how it is read.

If it appears just by itself (i.e. as 木 without any preceding or following kanji), it should be read き.

---

FYI: 木材 is commonly もくざい, but [きざい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%9C%A8%E6%9D%90_%28%E3%81%8D%E3%81%96%E3%81%84%29/#jn-51534) seems acceptable as well.

Comment: I feel like き＼ざい would almost always be (mis)understood as 機材 if used in speech...